# Calculating inactive session time when browser is closed and reloaded in java

Tags: java, browser, httpsession

Hi I have the below code in my project to check and validate the session.

```
javax.servlet.http.HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();

    // If the session is new
    if (httpSession.isNew())
    {
        errorCode = 2;
        errorMessage = "Invalid HTTP session";
        return false;
    }

    // If there is a Inactivity of 20 minutes, we expire the session on
    // server
    long now = new java.util.Date().getTime();
    long accessedTime = httpSession.getLastAccessedTime();
    if ((now - httpSession.getLastAccessedTime()) >= (MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL * 1000L))
    {
        errorCode = 2;
        errorMessage = "Inactivity of 20 minutes";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        httpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval((int) MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL);
    }
```

EVerything works fine. But when the user closes the browser, and opens it, the session is still active. When i debugged the code, `now - httpSession.getLastAccessedTime()` is 0. Or in other words, both are same values. How can I check the session when user closes the browser?

Edit: The issue is when the browser is again loaded with the url, the lastaccessedtime also gets updated.

Comment: What does `getCreationTime()` show when you open a new browser?

Comment: getCreationTIme() gives the time when session is created. However it cannot be used to find if the user is inactive or not

Comment: What I mean is that after closing and re-opening the browser, does it equal `now` .. if so then that's the reason. The new session is equal to the current time, i.e. when you open the browser.

Comment: In that case then it's probably a cookie/database problem ... you have not stated how you are keeping state.

Comment: getCreationTime() is different from now and lastAccessedTime